# Use different configuration file for integration tests

Tags: scala, sbt, typesafe-config

I have an sbt project that has an integration test configuration defined. Build.scala:

```
  lazy val root =
    Project("root", file("."))
      .configs( IntegrationTest )
      .settings( Defaults.itSettings : _*)
```

build.sbt has (among other things):

```
    libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
      "org.scalatest" % "scala-test_2.10" % "1.0.8" % "test,it",
      "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.0")
```

Now I have a `reference.conf` file under `src/main/resources`:

```
resources {
    postgresAdapter {
        db = "prod"
    }
}
```

and similarly under `src/it/resources`:

```
resources {
    postgresAdapter {
        db = "integration"
    }
}
```

I have a following class:

```
class PostgresAdapter{
  private val db = ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("resources").getString("postgresAdapter.db")

  private def connection: Try[java.sql.Connection] = {
    val _ = classOf[org.postgresql.Driver]
    Try(DriverManager.getConnection(s"jdbc:postgresql://dbserver/$db", "user", "password"))
  }
}
```

I want `db` to be initialized with `prod` if I do `sbt run` and initialized with `integration` when I do `sbt it:test`.
Is it possible to configure sbt and/or Typesafe config to have this effect or should I use different means for that?

PS: I'd like to avoid having `db_prod` and `db_integration` parameters in a config file that goes to production.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "configuration"? In sbt term, both `IntegrationTest` (aka `it`) and `Test` are called configuration. Do you mean to generate similar but slightly different files based on configuration?

Comment: See updated question. Hope it makes more sense

Comment: Ok now it's making sense to me. You're asking if different Typesafe config's configuration file could be used depending on different sbt configuration. The REAME says "first-listed are higher priority." What's the current behavior with the above setup? Is it not picking up `"integration"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could have an sbt problem (not getting your two folders on the classpath or not in the right order) or you could have a Typesafe Config problem (it isn't reading the two reference.conf which are on classpath).

Typesafe Config specifies the order it would load the two from the classpath: https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#conventional-configuration-files-for-jvm-apps

You could do a `klass.getClassLoader().getResources("reference.conf")` to see what order your two `reference.conf` are showing up. If you have the `src/it/resources` one first, it should be overriding the `src/main/resources` one which I think is what you want?

If you don't have both `reference.conf` on the classpath, then you have an sbt problem (or at least, your first problem is sbt) and you need to get that extra folder on the classpath.

There are also other ways you could handle this with Typesafe Config, such as loading an extra resource if present like `ConfigFactory.parseResources("testing.conf")` and overriding settings with that, or forking your integration tests and setting system properties on the jvm command line like `-Dresources.postgresAdapter.db` ... I'm sure there are other creative solutions too, just depends on what you want.

I'll make this a wiki and if your problem turns out to be an sbt problem Eugene can probably fix you up!

(If Typesafe Config isn't working as specified please file a bug at https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues )

Comment: Ha! It actually is working. The reason I did not see the results as expected is that I and a `truncate table` statement after test execution that removed the results. Thanks!